# Make item "Private" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, mongoid, elasticsearch, acl

App Attributes:

Rails 3.2, Mongoid, Devise, Elasticsearch

Basic Structure:

- User has a Post
- Post can be seen by other users

Situation:

A User wants to remove the post from being view-able by other users for a period of time.

*Note*
Eventually I would like to extend this capability so that its possible for said user to be able to make it only viewable to certain colleagues. This way they can collaborate on the post together.

Problem: 
I can't seem to think of a good way in rails to do this. One idea I had was to create a Boolean field in the post model that would allow me to achieve some of this but the ACL's would tricky and unstable at best. So I'm reaching out to the great intelligence this should be cake for some of you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggest is the one that occurs to me. Place a boolean flag `private` on the Post model, and modify the code you use to fetch Posts to exclude ones with the flag set unless they belong to the current user, (depending on whether private posts are viewable by their owner in that particular context).

I haven't actually worked with Mongoid, but I believe this is as simple as `Post.any_of({private: false}, {user_id: current_user.id})`

If and when you implement the collaboration functionality you discuss, all you need to do is change that code again - fetch posts that are not private, or that belong to any one of a given set of users.